# Get Dos (8.3) filename

Tags: windows, go, short-filenames

I have a directory with filenames that contain “funny” characters. I'd like to get the dos (8.3) filename for the files. How can I do that? My language of choice is Go.

```
C:\...\foo>dir /x
 Volume in Laufwerk C: hat keine Bezeichnung.
 Volumeseriennummer: 329F-C2FE

 Verzeichnis von C:\...\foo

29.09.2018  16:22    <DIR>                       .
29.09.2018  16:22    <DIR>                       ..
23.07.2009  01:52             5.526 CW9463~1.PDF cöw.pdf
               1 Datei(en),      1.922.706 Bytes
               0 Verzeichnis(se), 48.235.646.976 Bytes frei
```

I'd like to get the `CW9463~1.PDF` filename instead of `cöw.pdf`.

(I will use this filename to open a file for reading.)

Comment: Find first in the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list) how to do that in C. Then search the equivalent function in Go (or write the stub for it)

Comment: Opening a file named `cöw.pdf` should not be a problem for a modern programming language. Why do you think GO isn't able to open it?

Comment: OK, one step closer: There is the `GetShortPathNameW` WinAPI and a similar named Go syscall `GetShortPathName` but with a signature that I don't understand yet.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Go can open it. The software I use can't do it, so I'd like to use Go to tell me the short name which then I'll pass to my legacy library.

Comment: you shouldn't use DOS 8.3 names to deal with them. It's better to use [fully-qualified paths](https://superuser.com/a/31674/241386) like  `\\?\C:\...\foo\cöw.pdf`

Comment: What kind of software isn't able to open that file in 2018? Is that an old DOS-Program? But why do you need Go for that? The shortname is already shown with your `dir /x` output. Can't you just pass that name to your program?

Comment: @phuclv The library does not work with characters outside codepage 1250.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  My software is written in Go, so I would just pass in the short name which works fine.

Comment: @a_h: There are uncounted programs even in 2018, that cannot deal with file names properly. There's a good number of programs, that fail on non-ASCII file names, and probably even more, that choke on file names containing spaces. Using the short file name is the canonical solution to keeping those programs happy. Note, that a user can disable automatic generation of 8.3 file names.

Comment: The files are likely on an NTFS volume (if we haven't reparsed to another volume via junction or symlink), which, unlike FAT, does not necessarily create legacy 8.3 names. This NTFS feature can be disabled, either for the entire system or per volume. Moreover, 8.3 names aren't implemented at all in ReFS. Be prepared for your workaround to fail if you have to support the general case instead of just getting it to work in this specific case.

Comment: @eryksun thank you for the warning, this is a very helpful information.

Comment: on NTFS and ReFS you can also create another hardlink/symlink to that file with a proper name and pass to the other application without the need of 8.3 file names

Comment: @phuclv, I'd try `GetShortPathName` first, which should always work for FAT32 and exFAT file systems. If the resulting name isn't 7-bit ASCII (i.e. ordinals less than 128), set the working directory to the file's directory to avoid problems with parent-directory names, and create a hardlink that replaces non-ASCII characters with underscores and appends an incremented count to the basename for uniqueness (e.g. c_w.001.pdf). Unfortunately, ReFS doesn't support hardlinks, just symlinks. Creating symlinks requires SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege -- typically granted only to elevated administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but it doesn't really help me. (See the comment/warning from @eryksun)

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func GetShortPathName(name string) (path string, err error) {
    lp, err := windows.UTF16PtrFromString(name)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    n := uint32(100)

    for {
        buf := make([]uint16, n)
        n, err = windows.GetShortPathName(lp, &buf[0], uint32(len(buf)))
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        if n <= uint32(len(buf)) {
            return windows.UTF16ToString(buf[:n]), nil
        }
    }
}
```